# Sencha Touch 2: how to navigate to the same screen from different tab bar item

Tags: extjs, tabbar

On HomeView I have a button that navigates to readyContainer view. And on the tabbar I have an item that also goes to readyContainer view. Now on readyContainer I have list of buttons. Please refer to ReadyContent.js above. I'm having issues as to which container do I have to use as reference to push views. If I went to  readyContainer from Home, and tap on buttons there, the controller would refer to homeContainer. If I went to readyContainer from the tab bar, should the controller refer to readyContainer? How do I know which view to be set as reference. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
refs: {
        readyContainer: 'readyContainer'
    }
```

or

```
refs: {
        homeContainer: 'homeContainer'
    }
```

main.js

```
Ext.define('COSD.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
requires: [
    'Ext.TitleBar',
],
config: {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    layout:'card',

    items: [

       {
        xtype:'homeContainer'
       },
       {
        xtype:'readyContainer'
       },
       {
        xtype:'emergencyscreenview'
       },
       {
        xtype:'allnews'
       }

    ]
}
});
```

homeContainer.js

```
Ext.define('COSD.view.HomeContainer',{
extend:'Ext.NavigationView',
xtype:'homeContainer',
config:{
    title:'Home',
    iconCls:'home',


    scrollable:true,
    styleHtmlContent:true,
    styleHTMLCls:'home',
    html:[].join(""),

    items:[


        {
            xtype:'newsContent'
        }
    ]

}

})
```

homeContent.js

```
Ext.define('COSD.view.HomeContent',{
extend:'Ext.Panel',
xtype:'newsContent',
config:{
    title:'San Diego County Emergency ',
    iconCls:'home',
    cls:'toolbar',
    layout:'vbox',

    items:[

            {

                xtype: 'button',
                id:'readyButton',
                  style:'border-radius:0',
                  cls:'ReadyImageButton',
                pressedCls:'ReadyImageButtonSelected',


    html:'<div class="mainbutton-container-green"> <div class="mainbutton-thumb"><img src="resources/images/AppHome_ReadyIcon-Default Platform.png" /></div><div class="mainbutton-content"><i> <h3 class="mainbutton-title">ReadySanDiego</h3><p>Plan, Prepare </p></i></div></div>',

           },
           {

                xtype: 'button',
                id:'emergencyButton',
                  style:'border-radius:0',
                  cls:'EmergencyImageButton',
               pressedCls:'EmergencyImageButtonSelected',

                html:'<div class="mainbutton-container-red"> <div class="mainbutton-thumb"><img src="resources/images/AppHome_EmergencyIcon-Default Platform.png" /></div><div class="mainbutton-content"><i> <h3 class="mainbutton-title">Emergency</h3><p>News, Maps, Shelters </p></i></div></div>',


           },
           { 

                xtype: 'label',
                cls:'NewsUpdate',
                html: 'News Updates'
            }, 
            { 

                xtype: 'label',
                cls:'LatestNews',
                //autoEl:{id:'timediv'}
                html: '<div id="timediv">Latest News | Refreshed: 8/2/2013 10:36:26 AM</div>'
            }, 

        {
                xtype:'list',
                id:'newslistContent',
                loadingText: "loading...",
                emptyText: '<div>No notes found.</div>',
                store:'HomeStore',
                itemTpl:'<div><p>{title}</p><p class="newsItemTitle">{publishedDate}</p></div>',
                 flex: 1,
            plugins: [
        {
            xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
            pullRefreshText: 'Pull to refresh...',


        },
        {
            xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
            autoPaging: true,

        }
    ],
        }
    ]
}
})
```

ReadyViewContainer.js

```
Ext.define('COSD.view.ReadyViewContainer',{
extend:'Ext.NavigationView',
xtype:'readyContainer',
config:{
    title:'Ready',
    iconCls:'home',

    scrollable:true,
    styleHtmlContent:true,
    styleHTMLCls:'home',
    html:[].join(""),

    items:[


        {
            xtype:'readyContent'
        }
    ]

}

})
```

ReadyContent.js

```
Ext.define('COSD.view.ReadyContent', {
extend:'Ext.Panel',
xtype:'readyContent',

config: {
    title:'Ready',
    iconCls:'home',
    layout:'vbox',
    scrollable:true,
    styleHtmlContent:true,
    styleHTMLCls:'home',
    html:[].join(""),
    items:[


{

                xtype: 'button',
                id:'prepareDisaster',
                  style:'border-radius:0',
                  cls:'NavButtonListing',
                 pressedCls:'NavButtonListingSelected', 


                html:'<div class="ButtonListings-container"> <div class="ButtonListings-thumb"><img src="resources/images/CoSD_PrepareIcon-Default Platform.png" /></div><div class="ButtonListings-content"><h3 class="listbutton-title">Prepare for Disasters</h3></div></div>',

           },
]


 }

});
```

ReadyViewController.js

```
Ext.define('COSD.controller.ReadyViewController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    control: {
        '#prepareDisaster': {
            tap: 'prepareDisasterTap'
        }
    },
     refs: {
        readyContainer: 'readyContainer'
    }
},


prepareDisasterTap: function() {

                                        this.getReadyContainer().push({xtype:   'preparedisasterscreenview'})


}
});
```

Thanks for explaining the usage of id's. Sorry about not being clear about the issue I'm having. I'm having trouble explaining the scenario. I have an option to navigate to ReadyViewContainer using  id:'readyButton', on the home screen and from the tab bar at the bottom called xtype:'readyContainer'). I only have one version of this ReadyViewContainer. If the user tap on readyButton, it navigates to ReadyViewContainer but the active tab is the Home tab. If the user selected the 'Ready' icon on tab bar , it will also navigate to ReadyViewContainer and the active tab bar would be 'Ready'. ReadyViewContainer has a button called preparefordisaster. So that means the user could have gotten to this screen from either the Ready tab bar(active tab is 'Ready') or the readyButton on home screen(active tab is 'Home'). When the user selects preparefordisaster which container do I use to push the view because I wouldn't know if the user got to this screen from  the button on home view or the Ready tab bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely follow your post, but I will try to answer...

First, you shouldn't really use `id` on your components unless you know 100% that you will only use that component one time, and you will only not use that ID for any other component.  If you want to use an ID for a component, use `itemId`, which provides a *relative* path to obtain a component based on ID.

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    itemId: 'emergencyButton',
    style:'border-radius:0',
    //...etc...
},
```

Using that knowledge, you can combine it with the fact that you can use multiple `refs` within your controllers, and you can use longer selectors also (e.g. `emerButton: 'homeContainer #emergencyButton'`).

```
Ext.define('COSD.controller.ReadyViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        control: {
            'readyContent #prepareDisaster': {
                tap: 'doPrepareDisaster'
            },
            'homeContent #emergencyButton': {
                tap: 'doEmergencyButton'
            },
        },
        refs: {
            readyContainer: 'readyContainer',
            homeContainer: 'homeContainer'
        }
    },

    doPrepareDisaster: function() {
        this.getReadyContainer().push({ xtype: 'preparedisasterscreenview' });
    },

    doEmergencyButton: function() {
        this.getHomeContainer().push({ xtype: 'emergency-screen-view' });
    }
});
```

So, when pushing your views, you should push them onto the correct `NavigationView`, since that is the view that will be active when you tap that button.

Comment: You're great. I'm sorry I didn't understand the second part of your post. I created 2 tap functions, one that pushed to HomeContainer and the other pushes to ReadyContainer.This works. One more question, since readyContainer is a navigation view, pushing it to homecontainer(a nav view) causes the screen to have two title bars. Any help?

Comment: I wouldn't push one `NavigationView` onto another.  Just make the `readyContainer` a normal `Container`, with a `title` config.

Comment: I had to make readyContainer a Navigation view because it needs to be accessed from the bottom tab bar.